# How can I recognize the scroll direction using android listAdapter?

Tags: java, android, list, adapter

I have an andoird ListView and a ListAdapter.

I want to fetch blocks of 20 items from the server each time.

How would you suggest me to do efficient paging?

I have thought to fetch an new block of 10 items whenever getView returns item in position 10X.

I'll fetch 10 new items to the beginning if the user scrolled up, and 10 new items to the end if the user scrolled down.

I though to detect the scroll direction using a boolean flag (`isPassedNinthItem`) to know if 9X was before current 10X item (otherwise it was 11Xth item)

Any Easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the source for some of the *endless scroll* listviews, basically what you do is implement an `onScrollListener` and load the next 'page' (replace with your logic, an offset for instance) if all conditions are met:

```
public class EndlessScrollListener implements OnScrollListener {

    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int currentPage = 0;
    private int previousTotal = 0;
    private boolean loading = true;

    public EndlessScrollListener() {
    }
    public EndlessScrollListener(int visibleThreshold) {
        this.visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                currentPage++;
            }
        }
        if (!loading &amp;&amp; (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // I load the next page of gigs using a background task,
            // but you can call any function here.
            new LoadGigsTask().execute(currentPage + 1);
            loading = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
    }
}
```

[Source](http://benjii.me/2010/08/endless-scrolling-listview-in-android/)

Comment: can you please explain: `(totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold))` ?